# wrong size of IJVM chunk file in c question

Tags: c, binaryfiles, sizeof, ftell, ijvm

I am trying to implement an IJVM an read a binary file.

I understand that an .ijvm file contains a 32-bit magic number and any number of data blocks and that a data block has three parts.
My intention is to first read and store the magic number which is always of constant size and then the data block to a different array. 
The .ijvm file looks like this:

> 1d ea df ad 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   00 00 00 07 10 30 10 31 60 fd ff

with the first 4 bytes (`1d ea df ad`) being the magic n. and the rest the data block.
After reading the file I determine the total size being 27 bytes, thus the rest should be 23 bytes.
However, no matter what I try, despite storing and reading correctly the magic and data parts, I always get a wrong data part size and not 23 bytes as I think it should.

```
byte_t bufferMagic[4];
byte_t *dataBlock;

FILE *fp;
uint32_t filelen;
uint32_t dataBlocklen;
fp = fopen(binary_file, "r");

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); //compute the size of the file
filelen = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fprintf(stderr,"file:%s is %d bytes long\n",binary_file,filelen); //outputs27

//read magic number
fread(bufferMagic,1,4,fp);
fprintf(stderr, "Magic number: 0x%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx%02hhx \n",
    bufferMagic[0],bufferMagic[1],bufferMagic[2],bufferMagic[3]);

//read data block
dataBlock = (byte_t*)malloc(sizeof(byte_t) * filelen - 4);
//dataBlocklen = ftell(fp); //outputs 4
dataBlocklen = sizeof(dataBlock); //outputs 8
fread(dataBlock,1,filelen - 4,fp); //reads data block correctly
```

can you please explain what am I missing? Why both dataBlocklen not giving 23 bytes?

Comment: Just a minor oops, sizeof(dataBlock) is always 8 in a 64-bit program.  The size of a pointer.  You already know the size but didn't use a variable to store it, it is sizeof(byte_t) * filelen - 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//dataBlocklen = ftell(fp); //outputs 4
```

Returns `4` because current file offset is at 4th byte as you did `fread` for magicnumber prior to `ftell`.

```
fread(bufferMagic,1,4,fp);
```

and

```
dataBlocklen = sizeof(dataBlock); //outputs 8
```

Returns `8` because `dataBlock` is pointer, thus `sizeof(pointer)` is `8 byte` on your machine.

Comment: @sirHoyle In fact you should do it for all the questions you have asked, this is how you show gratitude towards someone who have helped you.